# Spring Boot variable not used

Tags: spring-boot

I have a method in which I collect a `number` with which I create two dates, (`fromDate` and `toDate`). I have also created a variable that updates depending on the value of both dates.

```
LocalDate fromDate = LocalDate.of(year, 1, 1);
LocalDate toDate = LocalDate.of(year, 12, 31);

double vacationsPerWorkedDays = 0;
        if (fromDate.isBefore(toDate)) {
            vacationsPerWorkedDays = (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(fromDate, toDate) - AbsenceDays + 1)
                    * VACATION_DAYS_GEN_DAILY;
        }
```

The problem is that the variable `vacationsPerWorkedDays` says it is not used, so I can't update it. I do not understand why this error occurs, I need to know how I should use it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually says that you are not using the variable in the upcoming code. Do something with that variable and that warning will go away.

Comment: But yes I am using the variable in the condition to update its value ``vacationsPerWorkedDays = (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(fromDate, toDate) - AbsenceDays + 1) * VACATION_DAYS_GEN_DAILY;``

Comment: That's not considered a usage. You need to do something with the value afterwards. It is still considered an unused variable until you use it in a calculation or print it or anything else